# how do I combine autocomplete with geocode to get Lat. & Lng. from form input in this autocomplete function?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, geocoding

I'm making this form where the user types in their postcode and it **autocompletes** the full address from google.maps.places dropdown list. The only thing that's missing is the **latitude** and **longitude** which I intend to make hidden fields for and then **onsubmit** post to my google sheets spreadsheet in the appropriate fields.

What I'm stuck on, is combining the **Geocoding API call**, with the Autocomplete Javascript function. What I'm trying to do, is add in a Geocoding API call with the autocomplete function so that the Lat. and Lng is sent to the hidden fields, I've been trying to figure this out for 3 days, I wonder if anyone has a **solution**.

Here is the code I have:

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
  var componentForm = {
    street_number: 'short_name',
    route: 'long_name',
    locality: 'long_name',
    administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
    country: 'long_name',
    postal_code: 'short_name'
  };

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST" 
              action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzF_r-4ENEXSMD36Ry_gQ9iSQ5dqfpZiw3VytR7LmpSAwxbEcRelxhGJroi8QCBavEI/exec"
              autocomplete="off" class="form" role="form">
                <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">
                
                <div class="form-group row">
                  
                  <label>Business address</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    
                    <input id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" autofill="off" placeholder="Postcode" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text"
                      class="form-control">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>Number</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="No."  class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="false" required>
                  </div>
                  <label>Street</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="Street"  class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true" required>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>City</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="City"  class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true" required>
                  </div>
                  <label>State</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="State" class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>Postal/zipcode</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="Postcode"  class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true" required>
                  </div>
                  <label>Country</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="Country"  class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group row">
                  <label>Lat</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="Lat"  class="form-control" id="Lat" disabled="true" required>
                  </div>
                  <label>Lng</label>
                  <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input name="Lng"  class="form-control" id="Lng" disabled="true">
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            <div class="form-group row">
              
              <div id="submit">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit" >Submit</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </form>
            <script
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
        async defer></script>
```

Now I also have this code snippet for calling the google geocoding API

```js
 document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevent form submit
    const place = autocomplete.getPlace(); //get place from autocomplete
    if (!place || !place.geometry) { //check if valid location
      swal("You have provided an Invalid address","Enter a valid Address", "warning");
      return;
    }
    // It is valid, proceed to geocode!
    else {
      // Listen for form submit
      document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', geocode);
      function geocode(e){
        // Prevent actual submit
        e.preventDefault();
        var location = document.getElementById('location-input').value; //* I think this is where I might have made a mistake
        axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
            params:{
                address: location,
                key: 'YOUR_API_KEY'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response){
            // Log full response
            console.log(response);
    
            // Formatted Address
            var formattedAddress = response.data.results[0].formatted_address;
            
            // Address Components
            var addressComponents = response.data.results[0].address_components;
    
            // Get values from the input fields
            var veg_planted = getInputVal('veg_planted');
        
            // Get geometry 
            var lat = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            var lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
            var coords= (formattedAddress + ": " + lat + "," + lng);
            console.log(coords);
    
            // Save messages
            saveMessage(veg_planted, coords);
            
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
    }
  });
```

Can this function be integrated with the autocomplete function I have to make the form fill out Lat. and Lng. values? If anyone out there has the solution it would help me a lot. Thank you.

Comment: I've removed the API key from the post for security and privacy concerns. Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use the geocoder. The places API returns the lat/lng coordinates in its response (if it has them).

> [PlaceResult.geometry](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceResult.geometry)
> geometry *optional*   
> Type:  PlaceGeometry *optional*
> The Place’s geometry-related information.

> [PlaceGeometry interface](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/places-service#PlaceGeometry)
> Defines information about the geometry of a Place.
> **Properties**
> **location** *optional*   
> **Type:**  LatLng *optional*
> The Place’s position.

```
document.getElementById("Lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
document.getElementById("Lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

**working code snippet:**

```js
var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

function fillInAddress() {
  // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

  for (var component in componentForm) {
    document.getElementById(component).value = '';
    document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
  }
  document.getElementById("Lat").value = place.geometry.location.lat();
  document.getElementById("Lng").value = place.geometry.location.lng();

  // Get each component of the address from the place details
  // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
  for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
    var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
    if (componentForm[addressType]) {
      var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
      document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
    }
  }
}

// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="myform" method="POST" action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzF_r-4ENEXSMD36Ry_gQ9iSQ5dqfpZiw3VytR7LmpSAwxbEcRelxhGJroi8QCBavEI/exec" autocomplete="off" class="form" role="form">
  <input autocomplete="false" name="hidden" type="text" style="display:none;">

  <div class="form-group row">

    <label>Business address</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

      <input id="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" autofill="off" placeholder="Postcode" onFocus="geolocate()" type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Number</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="No." class="form-control" id="street_number" disabled="false" required>
    </div>
    <label>Street</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="Street" class="form-control" id="route" disabled="true" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>City</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="City" class="form-control field" id="locality" disabled="true" required>
    </div>
    <label>State</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="State" class="form-control" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true">
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Postal/zipcode</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="Postcode" class="form-control" id="postal_code" disabled="true" required>
    </div>
    <label>Country</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="Country" class="form-control" id="country" disabled="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label>Lat</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="Lat" class="form-control" id="Lat" disabled="true" required>
    </div>
    <label>Lng</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <input name="Lng" class="form-control" id="Lng" disabled="true">
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">

    <div id="submit">
      <button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB_MrpX85obMpsk_eEdfE-iPIt06qbHyt0&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete" async defer></script>
```